# What is the practical limit to the wand length for a pressure washer?

Tags: cleaning, pipe, pressure-washer

The task involves pressure washing soffits that are 25-30 feet above ground level.  Is there a practical limit to the length of wand?  Any lessons-learned or pitfalls to avoid are appreciated.

Comment: I would say that if wand extensions are not commercially available, then there are problems that make them useless in practice.

Comment: Is a vertical jet sufficient, or must it also be angled around architectural details? I ask because of the potential torque on such a long lever.

Answer (score 1):

The length is mostly limited by the width of the pipe in the wand.  So if you use a wand made for 6 feet and add 20 feet to it, you can expect the sheer weight of the wand to bend it.  Gravity works.

Comment: Please clarify 'Gravity works'.  Thank you   Based on this comment it would be wise to buy a single 25 unit fiberglass or similar unit